# Accessing Tensorboard on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tcp, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to access Tensorboard on AWS. Here is my setting :

- Tensorboard : `tensorboard --host 0.0.0.0 --logdir=train` :

> Starting TensorBoard b'39' on port 6006 (You can navigate to
>   http://172.31.18.170:6006)

- AWS Security groups (in):

  - HTTPS      TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0
  - Custom_TCP TCP 6006  0.0.0.0/0

However connecting to `ec2-blabla.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:6006` I can't see anything, I basically can't connect.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: In chrome, you can hit `Ctrl-Shift-I` or right-click "Inspect", then click on Network. You'll see the network trace, and find out what it is trying to do. It might be that some links refer to the internal IP address. On linux, if memory serves, you can use iptables to redirect the internal address to the public IP.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. @Fabio, I added to the inbound rules and tried both 8080 and 6006 getting the same failure.

Comment: I'd be happy if you could signal whether your question has been answered and mark one answer as a solution (if it helped reach your goal). Thanks

Comment: The answers did not help, it was more of an AWS latency if I recall but these answers may still help people

Answer (score 24):

You can use ssh tunneling technique.

In your terminal:

```sh
ssh -i /path/to/your/AWS/key/file -NL 6006:localhost:6006 user@host
```

where:

- user and host: your aws ec2 user and instance specific.
- `-N`: don't execute a remote command (just forward ports)
- `-L`: `[bind_address:]port:host:hostport`

After that, browse to http://localhost:6006/

Comment: This one works for me. With this port forwarding/redirect, we don't even need the custom TCP port 6006 set in AWS instance security group. Thanks.

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer, works like a charm :)

Comment: This one worked for me. I wasted almost an hour dabbling with security groups configuration as recommended in AWS doucmentation without any success. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

1. Run tensorboard in your ec2 terminal (you can custom logdir and port)

   ```
   tensorboard --logdir=data/model --port=8080
   ```
2. Find your workstations public ip (a.b.c.d) address by visiting `http://ip4.me/`
3. Access the security group configuration assigned to your EC2 and add a custom TCP rule to your inbound traffic.

   [image: Security group inbound traffic configuration]
4. Outbound should be set to allow traffic from tensorboard port. (In this case 8080). Or you just allow all outgoing traffic from your EC2 instance

   ```
   Protocol       Port Range      Destination      Description   
   All traffic    All             All               0.0.0.0/0
   ```
5. Use your public DNS to access tensorboard from your workstation

   http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/

Answer (score 4):

**Fast (but unsecure) solution:**

Run:

```
tensorboard --logdir=/training --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080
```

on your AWS instance.

Make sure that both your inbound and outbound rules on AWS console (control center) are as unrestricted as possible (allow all types, all ports etc.). However, keep in mind that this solution is not recommendable for environments requiring security (in our case, we didn't consider security for training an NN).

An attempt to explain why this works: when the policy is set as described, AWS still seems to prohibit inbound/outbound connections on the standard tensorboard port 6006. This does not seem to apply to the port 8080.

**Long (but more secure) solution:**
See: https://blog.altoros.com/getting-started-with-a-cpu-enabled-tensorflow-instance-on-aws.html
(provides explanations for setting ports correctly on AWS)

Answer (score 4):

I managed to set it up like this:

- Go to security groups in your ec2 console:

[image]

- Choose the relevant security group in the table, click edit.
- Add a rule like this:

[image]

- Start tensorboard: `tensorboard --logdir tf_summary/ --port 8080`
- Find out the URL of your instance and visit `http://yourURL:8080`

Answer (score 1):

Simply run the tensorboard without the host parameter (which poses restrictions)

```
tensorboard --logdir XXX --port 6006
```

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from the same problem for several days.

Fortunately I solved this issue by adding rule on "AWS Outbound rule" as if I had added "AWS Inbound rule".

---

Regardless of this setting, it works at home.
*The same error is still happening only in the company.*

Comment: Could you please include details of the rule as the current description would not help future viewers fix their own problem.

Comment: I try again, but I can not connect again. T.T

Comment: It succeeded again.
By the way, I was still at home this time. When it did not connect, it was company.
"AWS Outbouned rule" does not need to be added.
It seems to be related to the firewall in the company.
To summarize the error situation, the company works only with jupiter Notebook and tensorboard is not enough.